# Create a Macro variable with dates in SAS

Tags: date, sas, sas-macro

I have two datasets - one with accountid and different dates corresponding to each accountid. The data looks something like this

| Accountid | Account open_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 21st Nov 2020 |
| 1254268 | 30 Nov 2020 |

and the second data is a transaction level daily data which looks something like this which has daily balance for each account ID.

| Accountid | transaction_date | Customer_Bal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 21st Nov 2020 | 400£ |
| 1254267 | 22 Nov 2020 | 100£ |
| 1254268 | 22 Nov 2020 | 50£ |
| 1254268 | 23 Nov 2020 | 0 |
| 1254268 | 24 Nov 2020 | 20£ |
| 1254268 | 25 Nov 2020 | 45£ |

There are 50 different accounts with different account open dates

I want to create a macro code, which fetches the different accountid's from the first table and then takes the balance from the second table from the account opening date to next ten days.

*I have created the macro for one date and then how to create the next ten days from that account open date*

```
proc sql;
select distinct account_open_date into :exec_date from abc 
order by account_open_date;

data _null_;
CALL SYMPUT('run0',put(intnx('day',&run.,0,'s'), yymmddn8.));
CALL SYMPUT('run1',put(intnx('day',&run.,1,'s'), yymmddn8.));
CALL SYMPUT('run2',put(intnx('day',&run.,2,'s'), yymmddn8.));
CALL SYMPUT('run3',put(intnx('day',&run.,3,'s'), yymmddn8.));
CALL SYMPUT('run4',put(intnx('day',&run.,4,'s'), yymmddn8.));
CALL SYMPUT('run5',put(intnx('day',&run.,5,'s'), yymmddn8.));
CALL SYMPUT('run6',put(intnx('day',&run.,6,'s'), yymmddn8.));
CALL SYMPUT('run7',put(intnx('day',&run.,7,'s'), yymmddn8.));
CALL SYMPUT('run8',put(intnx('day',&run.,8,'s'), yymmddn8.));
CALL SYMPUT('run9',put(intnx('day',&run.,9,'s'), yymmddn8.));
CALL SYMPUT('run10',put(intnx('day',&run.,10,'s'), yymmddn8.));
run;
```

**How to i store all the different account_open_dates in macro and then take out the the next ten days transactions from the second table for each accountid**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need macro for this processing.

A simple SQL join will get everything you need in a single table that can be further processed in `PROC` or `DATA` steps that use a `BY` statement.

Example:

Presume date variables contain SAS date values (which are integers for days from SAS date epoch).

```
proc sql;
  create table first_ten_days as
  select 
    accounts.account_id
  , accounts.open_date
  , transactions.transaction_date
  , transactions.balance
  from accounts
  join transactions
  on accounts.account_id = transactions.account_id
  where transactions.transaction_date - accounts.open_date <= 10
  order by account_id, transaction_date
  ;

proc ...
  by account_id;
  ...
```

Comment: Hi Richard, Thank you for the answer but apologies but I cannot understand what do you mean by the first sentence "Presume date variables contain SAS date values (which are integers for days from SAS date epoch)"

Comment: If the values are SAS dates, the where criteria `transactions.transaction_date - accounts.open_date <= 10` is appropriate.  If the date variables contain SAS datetime values a different where criteria is needed.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this Richard!

Answer (score 0):

Richard's right that you don't really need macro processing for this as explained, but let's say you did need it.

What you'd do is write your macro to take *one* account ID, and then run the code like this:

```
%macro pull_records(account_id=);
 %local exec_date;
 proc sql;
   select distinct account_open_date into :exec_date from abc 
   order by account_open_date
   where account_id = "&account_id"
 ;

 data want;
  set transactions;
  where account_id = "&account_id." 
    and transaction_date between (&exec_date.) and (&exec_date.+10);
 run;

 ... whatever else you are doing ...

%mend pull_records;

proc sql;
  select distinct cats('%pull_records(account_id=',account_id,')')
     into :pull_list separated by ' '
     from accounts
  ;
quit;

&pull_list.;
```

The macro pulls its own specific open date, and then does whatever it is you want to do with it.  If you're not doing things separately on each account, though, definitely do it Richard's way, it's really the only good way to do that.

Comment: Thanks Joe, this answer was very helpul too